# UK citizen marry Romanian citizen in Romania

Tags: visa, marriage, uk-citizens, europe, romanian-citizens

My fiance and i want to marry in romania.
I have my birth certificate and certificate of no impediment legalised (apostilled in the UK) and officially translated in Romanian.

We cannot get a clear answer from anyone if i need anything else. There is a lot of info online re this posted BEFORE brexit. Some are saying I need to go to the British embassy (and request what?) others are saying I don't. I can only stay in the country for 3 weeks before I'd have to leave again so I need to be as organised as possible.

Comment: Just to be clear: after marrying in Romania, would you want to settle there?  Also, does your fiance reside in Romania or elsewhere?  (I am not certain that it matters in Romania but in some countries at least one of the parties to the marriage must reside in the jurisdiction where the wedding takes place.)

Comment: Yes i would. I tried applying for a visa but it was so hard, long and ultimatley was denied. He lives there, the plan is to stay living with him. This is what the authorities are telling him can happen but im still not 100 percent sure. Thankyou so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

From https://dleps6.ro/starea-civila/inregistrarea-casatoriei/ (machine translated; there's a lot of text and formatting, so I have just copied and pasted the text without much regard to the formatting):

> Marriage between a Romanian citizen and a foreign citizen (mixed
> marriage)
>
> NECESSARY DOCUMENTS FOR PREPARING THE FILE
>
> Wife / Husband
>
> Identity documents   - passport (with visa - as the case may be),
> residence permit, etc. - valid both when submitting the file and when
> officiating the marriage - original and copy
>
> Birth certificate - in original and copy - with Apostille or
> superlegalized (as the case may be); Translated and legalized in
> Romania; Divorce sentence or death certificate - with Apostille or
> superlegalized, translated and legalized (as appropriate) Proof issued
> by diplomatic missions or consular offices accredited in Romania,
> showing that the husband, a foreign citizen, meets the substantive
> conditions required by his national law to conclude the marriage in
> Romania; - translated and legalized (as appropriate) Citizens whose
> states do not have a diplomatic mission or career consular office
> accredited in Romania will give a declaration on their own
> responsibility , authenticated by a notary public , showing that the
> future husband, foreign or stateless citizen, is not married and meets
> the substantive conditions required by its national law for the
> conclusion of marriage in Romania ; Citizens of the states with which
> Romania has concluded treaties / conventions / agreements of legal
> assistance, in civil matters and family law will present documents
> issued by the competent authorities of the respective countries -
> translated and legalized (as the case may be) Notarial declaration in
> Romania, showing that the substantive conditions required by Romanian
> law are met and there is no impediment to the conclusion of the
> marriage in Romania and the name after the marriage Wife / Husband
>
> Identity card - S6 - in original and copy Birth certificate - original
> and copy Divorce sentence or death certificate - as the case may be;
> Notarial declaration showing that the substantive conditions required
> by Romanian law are met and there is no impediment to the conclusion
> of the marriage in Romania and the name after the marriage
>
> PRENUPTIAL MEDICAL CERTIFICATES (family doctor) - 14 days valid
>
> MARRIAGE OFFICER - the 10th day from the submission of the complete file
>
> - OVERLEGALIZATION: - stamp of the MFA issuing state
>
> - the stamp of the Romanian Embassy / Consulate in the issuing state
> - MFA stamp from Romania
>
> In the case of concluding a marriage between a  Romanian citizen  and
> a  foreign citizen , the latter must present, in addition to the
> documents listed above, the proof issued by the diplomatic mission of
> the state of citizenship, accredited in Romania, showing that the
> foreign citizen fulfills the substantive conditions provided by its
> national law for concluding the marriage in Romania.
>
> The citizens of the states with which Romania has concluded  treaties
> / conventions / agreements  of legal assistance in civil matters and
> family law will present documents issued by the competent authorities
> of the respective countries. These states are:  the Republic of
> Albania, the Republic of Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Bosnia and
> Herzegovina, the Czech Republic, the People's Republic of China, the
> Democratic People's Republic of Korea, Croatia, the Republic of Cuba,
> the French Republic, the Republic of Moldova, the People's Republic of
> Mongolia, the Republic of Poland, Russia, Republic of Serbia, Slovakia,
> Slovenia, Republic of Hungary, Ukraine.
>
> The documents issued by these states are EXEMPTED FROM APOSTILIZATION
> and OVERLEGALIZATION.
>
> Citizens whose states do not have a diplomatic mission or consular
> office accredited in Romania will give statements on their own
> responsibility, authenticated by a notary public, showing that the
> future spouse, foreign citizen or stateless person, is not married and
> meets the substantive conditions required by its national law for the
> conclusion of the marriage.

Comment: Thankyou - so im reading that i need the documents i already have - certificate of no impediment, passport and birth certificate and permission from the british embassy - he needs a birth certificate, and his id card. Doctors appointnents and things can be easily obtained

Comment: @Ajurj yes, it looks that way, but I don't read Romanian and I certainly have no experience with Romanian authorities.  In light of your other comment saying that you would like to settle in Romania after the marriage, I would suggest that you try to find some local expertise on Romanian immigration law.  If you can't afford an immigration lawyer, perhaps there is an immigrants' rights society, or a more generalized legal aid society (or similar) that can offer advice or help you find it.